# emacs shortcut for switching to next function in scope

Tags: emacs

I want to swtich to the next and last function inside a c++-buffer. But I want to have it as a **shortcut** and not with imenu or anything else that lists all the available function.

If it is possible: How can I implement it? (I just have one main.cpp with many function and want to navigate faster.)

Comment: Maybe you should ask on emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: [This is what you want](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Defuns.html), which is the first google result for "emacs next previous function".